# How to sort like values in Python

Tags: python

I was wondering how to sort like values in a list, and then break like values into a sub-list.

For example: I would want a function that probably does something like

```
def sort_by_like_values(list):
    #python magic

>>>list=[2,2,3,4,4,10]
>>>[[2,2],[3],[4,4],[10]]
OR
>>>[2,2],[3],[4,4],[10]
```

I read up on the sorted api and it works well for sorting things within their own list, but doesn't break lists up into sub-lists. What module would help me out here?

Comment: `itertools.groupby()` is good for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from the itertools module.

```
from itertools import groupby

L = [2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 10]

L.sort()
for key, iterator in groupby(L):
    print key, list(iterator)
```

Result:

```
2 [2, 2]
3 [3]
4 [4, 4]
10 [10]
```

A couple of things to be aware of: `groupby` needs the data it works on to be sorted by the same key you wish to group by, or it won't work. Also, the iterator needs to be consumed before continuing to the next group, so make sure you store `list(iterator)` to another list or something. One-liner giving you the result you want:

```
>>> [list(it) for key, it in groupby(sorted(L))]
[[2, 2], [3], [4, 4], [10]]
```

Comment: Nailed it! Nice one. Especially liked the list comprehension in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Check the `itertools` module, it has the useful `groupby` function:

```
import itertools as i
for k,g in i.groupby(sorted([2,2,3,4,4,10])):
    print list(g)

....

[2, 2]
[3]
[4, 4]
[10]
```

You should be able to modify this to get the values in a list.

Answer (score 2):

As everyone else has suggested `itertools.groupby` (which would be my first choice) - it's also possible with `collections.Counter` to obtain key and frequency, sort by the key, then expand back out freq times.

```
from itertools import repeat
from collections import Counter

grouped = [list(repeat(key, freq)) for key, freq in sorted(Counter(L).iteritems())]
```

Answer (score 1):

`itertools.groupby()` with a list comprehension works fine.

```
In [20]: a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6]

In [21]: [ list(subgroup) for key, subgroup in itertools.groupby(sorted(a)) ]
Out[21]: [[1, 1], [2], [3, 3], [4], [5, 5, 5], [6]]
```

Note that `groupby()` returns a list of iterators, and you have to consume these iterators in order. As per the docs:

> The returned group is itself an iterator that shares the underlying iterable with groupby(). Because the source is shared, *when the groupby() object is advanced, the previous group is no longer visible.* So, if that data is needed later, it should be stored as a list:

Answer (score 1):

If you do not wish to use itertools and can wrap your head around list comprehensions, this should also do the trick :

```
def group(a):
    a = sorted(a)
    d = [0] + [x+1 for x in range(len(a)-1) if a[x]!=a[x+1]] + [len(a)]
    return [a[(d[x]):(d[x+1])] for x in range(len(d)-1)]
```

where `a`is your list